# What is an economic bubble?

Tags: economic-bubble

How do one know whether an appreciation in the price of an asset is a bubble or not? For example, during the 2007-2008 crisis, there was a housing bubble, which is only mainly agreed upon when the bubble actually starts to burst. Beforehand, however, the rise in housing price was not commonly accepted as a bubble, especially during the period when the housing price was still rising before the crisis.

So how do we know whether an appreciation is a bubble or not?

Any suggestions of articles about the issue are appreciated.

Comment: Some hardcore rational expectations researchers consider multiple equilibria as bubbles. They usually proceed by claiming that thus bubbles do not exist or are even beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a highly disputed question! There is a new and interesting paper by Òscar Jordà, Moritz Schularick and Alan M. Taylor about "[Leveraged bubbles](http://economics.ucdavis.edu/people/amtaylor/files/w21486.pdf)". They study bubbles in housing and equity markets in 17 countries over the past 140 years.